# How to use variable inside awk

Tags: bash

I am trying to print the server name in HTML 
I wrote the below code using awk -v to do that but the server name is not printing.

```
awk -v server="${svr}" 'BEGIN{
FS=","
print "==============================\n"
printf "<h2>ServerName :  ${server}</h2>"
print "=============================="
print  "<HTML>""<TABLE border="1">"
}
 {
printf "<TR>"
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
{
printf "%s", "<td"
if ($i+0==2) printf " bgcolor=#FF3333"
    else if ($i+0==1) printf " bgcolor=#FFCC33"
    else if ($i+0==4) printf " bgcolor=#99FF33"
print ">" $i "</td>"
}
print "</TR>"
 }
END{
print "</TABLE></BODY></HTML>"
 }
```

it is printing `ServerName :  ${server}`
Please let me know what i am missing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script

Comment: I checked the answer given at the link, same way i did but facing issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use in this way:

```
print "servername:" server
```

or:

```
printf "foo: %s bar", server
```

Comment: i need to use inside <h2>

Comment: @Sandy well just add `<h2>` then... `printf "foo bar %s whatever you want to add to the string", server`

Comment: btw, `printf "fixstring"` without filling parameter is considered as bad practice.

Comment: Tried
`printf "<h2>"ServerName:%s", server</h2>"` 
Error : 
`awk: cmd. line:4: printf "<h2>"ServerName:%s", server</h2>"
awk: cmd. line:4:                        ^ syntax error`

Comment: @Sandy ok, just take this: `printf "<h2>ServerName:%s</h2>", server` when I see `syntax error`, I would do a man awk/gawk to check out the right syntax of `printf`

Comment: Thanks Kent..it worked...:) Please update your answer so that i can accept.

Comment: ..........ok...